# REST API for Kubernetes apiserver proxy?

Tags: rest, proxy, kubernetes, kubectl, kubeadm

I have a K8s Cluster made from kubeadm v1.8.4 present on virtual machine. Now i want to access this K8s cluster using rest API from my laptop/workstation.

One way through which i am able to do this is by running this command "kubectl proxy --address=  --accept-hosts '.*' ".But i have to manually run this command in order to access my cluster from laptop and i don't want that.

While going through the docs i found that there is another proxy available which is **apiserver proxy**.I am trying to use this way by following this link(https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/access-cluster/#manually-constructing-apiserver-proxy-urls) but getting error "could not get any response" in postman.

So i was wondering whether i am using this apiserver proxy properly or not.Or is there any other way through which i can hit REST request from my laptop to my cluster on VM's without manually hitting "kubectl proxy" command?

Answer (score 0):

What kube proxy does for you is essentialy two things.

First, obviously, it proxies your traffic from a localhost port to kubernetes api.

Second, it also authenticates you against the cluster so that all the proxied calls do not neet authentication information.

To hit API directly, it's as simple as pointing your client to the right IP:PORT of your VM, but... you need to either ignore (not advised) tls issues or trust kube CA cert. Also, you still need to authenticate to it, so you need to use appropriate client credentials (ie. bearer token).

`Manually constructing apiserver proxy` refers to a different kind of beast, which allows you to proxy traffic to services deployed in your kubernetes cluster by means of accessing a particular path in kube API server. So to use that you need to have the access to the API already.